# Unix how to create files and directories with specific user

Tags: unix

I'm trying to create files and directories and executing a script with a specific user instead of root user. How can I do that?  I don't want to switch users from root user to another user; instead, I always want it to use a specific user, for example, wasadmin user.

Whenever I'm creating a new file or executing a script, this should be run as wasadmin user.  Can you please help me with this?

Comment: You should do as little as possible as `root` — it is dangerous to experiment as the superuser.  The best way to achieve your goal is to make the effective UID of the process creating the files into the `wasadmin` user.  The only alternative I know of is for your root privileged program to always create the file and then set the owner (and group?) to the preferred value.  This is an abnormal way of proceeding — it is far more painful than running as the relevant user.

Comment: Are there any special conditions for not just doing these jobs as "wasadmin" user? Login into a shell, run scripts, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you create the file. As far as I know, it's not possible to do this when you use `touch` or `echo`, but depending on the way you create the file, there might be a possibility to add a user parameter.

In case this is not possible, you might use the `chown` command (change ownership), this command gives the possibility to modify the owner/group of an already created file (which  obviously means that you can only do this after the file has already been created). I've been looking for an official `chown` reference, but I think that launching the command `man chown` can answer all questions you might have on this command.

Comment: On Unix, `chown` is both a command (POSIX: [`chown`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/chown.html); Linux: [`chown`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chown.1.html)) and a system call (POSIX: [`chown()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/chown.html); Linux: [`chown()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chown.2.html)).  (You're welcome to incorporate any or all of those links into your answer; you may then flag this comment as no longer needed.)